# Detect face from Live Video with Microsoft Cognitive service

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-cognitive-services

Currently, Working on project for detect face from Live Video and for this I am using MS cognitive service face api.
Previously,it is working fine but from today it is not working and gives error when I call face detect method.
The error like as "Rate limit is exceeded. Try again later."
Please suggest me what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you reached the limit of the free offer. You can not send more informations to decode for free.

The Video API says : "Free: 300 calls per month per feature"

You certainly reached the limit of 300 calls

**EDIT**

Moreover @cthrash specified that you can't send more than 5 reqs per minutes for getResults and 1 per minute for the other services

Comment: Just to be clear, there are two limits at play here: quota, and rate.  What you're referring to is the quota limit, but it sounds like the poster is actually bumping up against rate limits.  The video API has two different rate limits: 5/minute for getResult, 1/minute for everything else.

Comment: Yes I got that as per error says. But I had create a new account and generate new keys, after that use them instead of old ones. But again it gives same error. Please suggest me for that.

Comment: Has @cthrash said, you certainly reached the rate limit, go slower with your app. Don't send more than 1 requests per minute.